# R function for Parametric Survival Analysis that allows for modification of parameters

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I am trying to perform a set of survival analyses on surgical duration, with a set of covariates as controls. The purpose is to compare the coefficients and marginal effects of covariates across different distributional forms (e.g., exponential, Weibull, log-logistic). To help your understanding, suppose that the exponential model is defined as:
[exponential model specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kweW5.png) and with log-logistic distribution, the duration model can be specified as:
[log-logistic model specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7LyN.png)

**QUESTION**: I need to introduce explanatory variables, by replacing the parameter γ with exp(X_i * β).  Is there any R function that can allow me to modify such parameter?

**Sample data**

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
        X1 = sample(1:10),
        X2 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
        status = sample(1, 10, replace=TRUE),
        # no censoring. -- all entry and exit are recorded.
        surgical.duration = sample(1:10)
)
```

**Trial 1**: rms and survival Packages (psm function)

```
library(rms)
library("survival")

exp.model <- psm(Surv(surgical.duration, status) ~ 1 + X1 + X2,
                 data = Data, dist="exponential")
# Is there any way to put the parameter specification into this?
```

**Trial 2**: survival package (survereg and Surv functions)

```
exp.model2 <- survreg(Surv(surgical.duration, status) ~ 1 + X1 + X2,
                      data = Data, dist="exponential", parms = ) 
# Can I use this parms argument to specify the parameter?
summary(exp.model2)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., abstract from your real problem...

Comment: Thank you, I will re-read them again and try to improve it.

Comment: In fact, survreg does what I want. In the above, gamma is being replaced by exp(1+x1+x2).

Comment: I don't understand "introduce explanatory variables, by replacing the parameter γ with exp(X_i ...)"

Comment: Yeah I think you need to either add more maths or more code because currently it sounds like you want to manually change the fitted coefficients, which can't be right